# Default cache expiration behavior in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I already look for clear explanation about this but unfortunate to get answer to this type of question. I want to know how does Cache object expires in ASP.NET? does it expire per user? or it expires as a whole? if it expires as a whole? how can I override that behavior to make it expires only per users?

Comment: Cache is across users. Its not for individual user. For user specific data you need to use session. Or generate user specific cache keys to store data in cache.

Comment: @Chetan - you mean like this example?: Cache[user_id] where user_id is string variable? I cant use session because I'm getting performance problem because of its locking mechanism.

Comment: Cache (as in `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`) is a **global** entity - it doesn't work "per user". Also: when you add an item to the cache, you **must supply** a `CacheItemPolicy` to define how the item is retained (or ejected) from cache - there's no global default caching policy

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to cache, so we can be sure which `Cache` you are referring to.

Comment: @mjwills - the cache i'm referring is the one I replied to Chetan like so: Cache[user_id]=new object where user_id is a variable containing the user's id to get the cache.

Comment: Expiry is per item, thus each different `user_id` entry will expire at a different time.

Comment: @mjwills - that's what i'm asking from the start. thank you for clearing this to me. :)